# In finite element analysis, which boundary conditions affect the left hand side?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, surface-integrals, weak-derivatives, finite-element-method

I'm currently working on a problem related to heat transfer, and thus I encountered robin boundary condtions for the first time while working with the finite element method. Unlike neumann boundary conditions, which in the weak formulation $a(u,v) = l(v)$ are a part of the linear $l(v)$-term, I eventually figured out that the robin boundary condtitions end up in the bilinear term $a(u,v)$. So my question is this, how do we determine if the integral over the boundary belongs to the bilinear form, or the linear form?

For reference's sake, the weak formulation for a poisson problem with neumann boundaries look like this:
$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v d\Omega = \int_{\Omega} vf d\Omega + \int_{\partial \Omega} v \nabla u \cdot \vec{n} dS
$$

While the robin case would look something like this;

$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v d\Omega + \int_{\partial \Omega} v(u-T)dS = \int_{\Omega}vfd\Omega
$$

with $T$ being the ambient temperature. The only difference I can spot is that the terms on the boudary related to $u$ is not differentiated for robin boundary conditions. So how does this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would $\int_{\partial \Omega} v \nabla u \cdot \overline{n} dS$ be part of the linear form?

Comment: Sorry I skipped a detail, it would be a part of the linear form since the boundary condtion states $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{n}} = \nabla u \cdot \vec{n} = g$ on $\partial \Omega$. But honestly this sort of awnsers my own question, since all terms relating to $u$ then disappear in the neumann case.

Comment: Good that you answered your own question. Indeed, in that case, the r.h.s. integral is just a functional $ v \mapsto \int_{\partial \Omega } v g dS$.